# how to resolve data type incompatability issue in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to build below logic

```
Declare @OT float 
Declare @Remark varchar(100)
set @OT = 9.52
set @Remark = '1-25 hours'
select case when @Remark='1-25 hours'  then  (FLOOR((@OT * 100)/100)*150 + (((@OT * 100) % 100.00) * (150/60))) --@OT*150
                   when @Remark='26-35 hours' then (25*150) + ((FLOOR((@OT-25.00) * 100)/100 )*200 + (((@OT-25.00) * 100)%100) * (200/60))  --((@OT-25.00)* 200)
                   when @Remark='36-45 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + ( FLOOR(((@OT-35.00)*100)/100)*250 + (((@OT-35.00) * 100)%100) * (250/60)) --((@OT-35.00) * 250)
                   when @Remark='46-55 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (FLOOR(((@OT-45.00) *100)/100)*350 + (((@OT-45.00) * 100)%100) * (350/60)) --((@OT-45.00) * 350)
                   when @Remark='56-65 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (10 * 350) + (FLOOR(((@OT-55.00)*100)/100)*550 + (((@OT-55.00) * 100)%100) * (550/60)) --((@OT-55.00) * 550)
                   when @Remark='aboce 65 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (10 * 350) + (10 * 550) + (FLOOR(((@OT-65.00)*100)/100)*650 + (((@OT-65.00) * 100)%100) * (650/60)) --((@OT-65.00)* 650)
             end
```

But i am getting below error

***Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
The data types float and numeric are incompatible in the modulo operator.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast to `INT` before performing the `modulo`:

```
Declare @OT float 
Declare @Remark varchar(100)
set @OT = 9.52
set @Remark = '1-25 hours'

SELECT FLOOR((@OT * 100)/100)*150 + ((CAST(@OT * 100 AS INT) % 100.00) * (150/60))
```

Here is the complete code:

```
select case when @Remark='1-25 hours'  then  (FLOOR((@OT * 100)/100)*150 + ((CAST(@OT * 100 AS INT) % 100.00) * (150/60))) --@OT*150
                   when @Remark='26-35 hours' then (25*150) + ((FLOOR((@OT-25.00) * 100)/100 )*200 + (CAST((@OT-25.00) * 100 AS INT)%100) * (200/60))  --((@OT-25.00)* 200)
                   when @Remark='36-45 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + ( FLOOR(((@OT-35.00)*100)/100)*250 + (CAST((@OT-35.00) * 100 AS INT)%100) * (250/60)) --((@OT-35.00) * 250)
                   when @Remark='46-55 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (FLOOR(((@OT-45.00) *100)/100)*350 + (CAST((@OT-45.00) * 100 AS INT)%100) * (350/60)) --((@OT-45.00) * 350)
                   when @Remark='56-65 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (10 * 350) + (FLOOR(((@OT-55.00)*100)/100)*550 + (CAST((@OT-55.00) * 100 AS INT)%100) * (550/60)) --((@OT-55.00) * 550)
                   when @Remark='aboce 65 hours' then (25*150) + (10*200) + (10* 250) + (10 * 350) + (10 * 550) + (FLOOR(((@OT-65.00)*100)/100)*650 + (CAST((@OT-65.00) * 100 AS INT)%100) * (650/60)) --((@OT-65.00)* 650)
             end
```

The issue is you are not allowed to perform `modulo`, because:

> dividend must be a valid expression of any one of the data types in
> the integer and monetary data type categories, or the numeric data
> type.

and even you multiply with `100`, you are not changing the type.